# Last 6 unique dates from array with corresponding columns in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Good day everyone. Thanks in advance for answering my question.
Please, I want and excel solution to this problem. I have searched the forum but no clear solution.

I have an excel sheet with columns A, B, C ,D and E. Column A holds date info, B holds Home team, C holds Away team, D holds goals score, E holds goal Away scored. Example below

**DATE        HOME           AWAY     FTHG FTAG**

```
23-11-2017  Man City       Arsenal   3     2
23-11-2018  Sunderland     West Ham  3     2
03-12-2017  Man United     Man City  2     2
23-12-2017  Man City       Arsenal   1     2
15-02-2018  Sunderland     Man City  3     2
20-02-2018  Sunderland     Chelsea   3     2
23-02-2018  Brighton       Man City  3     2
03-04-2018  Man City       Arsenal   3     5
23-03-2018  Everton        Burnley   1     1
```

I want to know the last six matches played by Man City with their corresponding opponent and the scores. The formula should return the following

DATE        HOME           AWAY     FTHG FTAG

```
23-11-2017  Man City       Arsenal   3     2
03-12-2017  Man United     Man City  2     2
23-12-2017  Man City       Arsenal   1     2
15-02-2018  Sunderland     Man City  3     2
23-02-2018  Brighton       Man City  3     2
03-04-2018  Man City       Arsenal   3     5
```

I have managed to use  `'=VLOOKUP(LARGE(A:A,1),A:E,1,0) IN CELL(1:7)'`
 
Example

```
    'Cell(1,7)=VLOOKUP(LARGE(A:A,1),A:E,ROW()-1,0)'
    'Cell(1,8)=VLOOKUP(LARGE(A:A,2),A:E,ROW()-1,0)'
    'Cell(1,9)=VLOOKUP(LARGE(A:A,3),A:E,ROW()-1,0)'
    'Cell(1,10)=VLOOKUP(LARGE(A:A,4),A:E,ROW()-1,0)'
    'Cell(1,11)=VLOOKUP(LARGE(A:A,5),A:E,ROW()-1,0)'
    'Cell(1,12)=VLOOKUP(LARGE(A:A,6),A:E,ROW()-1,0)'
```

But the problem is when it encounter same dates it chooses anyone, especially the last one. Any help please?

Comment: Why not just use the `Advanced Filter`?

Comment: is your code (once uncommented) really working? Is “Cell” an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need LARGE unless you keep the *k* parameter at 1. What you need is to find the maximum value (i.e. date) that has not been collected already. An array formula MAX or LARGE or xl2010's AGGREGATE can accomplish this.

In G2 use one of these:

```
'array formula with CSE
=MAX(IF(ISNA(MATCH(A$2:A$10, G$1:G1, 0)), A$2:A$10))
=LARGE(IF(ISNA(MATCH(A$2:A$10, G$1:G1, 0)), A$2:A$10), 1)
'standard formula without CSE
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, (A$2:A$10)/(G$1:G1<>A$2:A$10), 1)
```

Once you have the 6 unique dates, VLOOKUP can return the remaining information.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I really appreciate your assistance. Thanks guys. Both of you are just too brilliant.!

Comment: For updates, I have corrected the Arsenal score and dates. It was typo. Thanks